# sklearn C-SVC with iris dataset to get classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am willing to use a SVM to predict the classes of the IRIS dataset of sklearn. Using WEKA I could get a 100% prediction using LibSVM. In Pyton, LibSVM seems to be implemented in SVR. So I tried to use SVR but the results I get are not classes (0, 1, 2) but numbers (result of the regression).

If I execute this code with same parameters as WEKA LibSVM:

```
import numpy
from sklearn import svm, datasets

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
model = svm.libsvm.fit(kernel = 'rbf', svm_type=0, X=iris.data,         
Y=iris.target.astype(numpy.float64), C=10, gamma = 10, epsilon = 0.01,     coef0=0, random_seed=0)
pred = svm.libsvm.predict(iris.data, *model)
pred = pred.astype(numpy.int)
print(pred)
```

I get the following result:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2
 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2
 2 1]
```

while WEKA will probably produce `[ 0, ..., 0, 1, ... 1, 2, ..., 2]`. I was wondering why I couldn't get the same results using the same parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `SVC`, not `SVR`, or a choice from among the other [SVM classifiers](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#classification).

What constraint do you have that forces you to use specifically libsvm? Can you not also use liblinear? I am not sure this matters though, since the support vector classifiers inherit from the abstract base class [`BaseLibSVM`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/svm/base.py#L60), meaning that `SVC` will also use libsvm by default.

It also looks like you can use the [svm.libsvm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit.html) subpackage if you like. There, even though the input data are treated as float64, the default mode is `C_SVC`, which means it will treat the float target values like they are class labels, and the predictions will be class labels.

Comment: my concern is that using WEKA I could get a 100% classification, i.e the prediction gives me same result in terms of classes as the expected classes. I want to obtain the same result in python. But using SVC or SVR I always get some misclassified instances. So I thought that it came from the implementation of SVC/SVR. But using libsvm I get more errors:

With the same parameters as WEKA for C, gamma, kernel,... I get 14 misclassified instances

Comment: @Jean-MichelRicher Your comment is not fully clear. If you are using SVR (which is a *regression* model), then the prediction outputs will not make sense... they will be floating point values along a continuum, and will not represent class labels. Are you quantizing them by rounding or something? Separately, can you post the SVC (*not* SVR) code in your question, exactly as you are using it, so we can reproduce the incorrect examples?